# Macro that links JLS paragraphs

Tags: macros, paragraphs, links

I am trying do define a macro that automatically links to a paragraph in the Java Language Specifications. But for some reason, it is not working.

I want to call the command with a paragraph number, e.g. `\pg{6.6}`, and it should display as `§6.6` which links to the correct JLS entry (in this case this link http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.6).

This is what I have so far:

```
\newcommand{\pg}[1]{\href{http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-6.html\# jls-{#1}}{§#1}}
```

But this code causes a problem with the link. It is not working correctly. When I hover over the text, it indicates a link, but clicking won't do anything.

Another problem is that this command would only work for paragraphs in chapter 6, because of the chapter declaration in the link. Is there a way around this?

**EDIT:** This my current solution which is based on Davids Solution and uses the `xstring` package:

```
\newcommand{\pg}[1]{%
    \StrLeft{#1}{1}[\firstletter]%
    \href{http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-\firstletter.html\#jls-#1}{§#1}%
}
```

It has the advantage that it works with paragraphs like 5.3.1.4 and does not need more than one argument. I can just use it like this: `\pg{5.3.1.4}`

Comment: you were nearly there but you put a space and a spurious `{}` into the URL your URL ended `html# jls-{6.1}` not `html#jls-6.1`

Comment: For me using evince and firefox the link works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand{\pg}[2]{%
\href{http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-#1.html\#jls-#1.#2}%
{\textsection#1.#2}}
\begin{document}


zzz\pg{6}{1}

\end{document}
```